# Refactor similar Spring MVC ExceptionHandlers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I have below exception handlers *repeated* in couple Spring MVC controllers. I know those can be refactored into a *single bean* or into WebMvcConfigurerAdapter but I couldn't find any examples. I don't have any views, it's a REST API...

How can I refactor those with java configuration? If possible I'd prefer to refactor those into a custom WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
......
......
@ExceptionHandler({MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
    UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException.class,
    HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
    ServletRequestBindingException.class,
    TypeMismatchException.class
})
public ResponseEntity<DataCarrier> handleException(Exception exception) {
    logger.warn("A bad input received.");
    return new ResponseEntity<DataCarrier>(new ErrorDto("Input data is not valid."), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

@ExceptionHandler({AccountNotFoundException.class, NoAccountException.class})
public ResponseEntity<DataCarrier> noAccountFoundException(Exception exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<DataCarrier>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}

@ExceptionHandler({HeaderPropertyException.class})
public ResponseEntity<DataCarrier> headerPropertyException(Exception exception) {
    logger.error("[{}].", exception.getMessage(), exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<DataCarrier>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's possible then? Intuition? A better solution would be to add a [ControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

Comment: Ok I solved the problem by adding a ControllerAdvice, refactored all the scattered exception handlers in one place.